# NServiceBus Single Server Installation

Tags: nservicebus

I'm looking at designing a commercial web site from scratch in the new year and I was planning on using NServiceBus.  Other components would include RavenDB, ASP.NET MVC, Ninject, Bootstrap, etc.

My question is, if I build scalability in from the beginning, particularly if in the first 6 months I plan to run the site from a single server, would it be a foolish thing to use NServiceBus from the outset?  Will I experience much of a choke-point by pushing everything through MSMQ rather than direct calls to methods in DLLs?  Should NServiceBus only be added to mature systems, or systems that are intended to be deployed to more than one server?

Comment: Impossible to answer without a lot more context.  What do you intend to use NSB for in your system?  What does the web application do?  Are you expecting 1000 transactions per second or 1000 per year?  Also, keep in mind that NSB support transports besides MSMQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the fastest possible call would be a direct in-memory invocation, I wouldn't look at optimizing for latency of calls in most web scenarios. Instead, focus on what type of logic can be run asynchronously with respect to the user request. That will be most influential on your overall scalability.

NServiceBus provides a fairly clean programming model for asynchronous invocations that can later on be distributed across multiple processes and machines.